# Failing to deploy a aiogram python bot in webhook mode

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, telegram-bot

I have tried this script which is similar to [aiogram official example](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/webhook_example.py) for webhook deployment.

```py
import os
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor

PROJECT_NAME = os.environ.get("PROJ")
TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")

WEBHOOK_HOST = f"https://{PROJECT_NAME}.herokuapp.com"
WEBHOOK_PATH = "/webhook/" + TOKEN
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

WEBAPP_HOST = "localhost"
WEBAPP_PORT = 8443

bot = Bot(TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# Example handler
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="hi")


# Run after startup
async def on_startup():
    await bot.delete_webhook()
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)


# Run before shutdown
async def on_shutdown():
    logging.warning("Shutting down..")
    await bot.delete_webhook()
    await dp.storage.close()
    await dp.storage.wait_closed()
    logging.warning("Bot down")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if "HEROKU" in list(os.environ.keys()):
        executor.start_webhook(
            dispatcher=dp,
            webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
            on_startup=on_startup,
            on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
            skip_updates=True,
            host=WEBAPP_HOST,
            port=WEBAPP_PORT,
        )
    else:
        executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Polling worked fine for a few seconds and then crashed.

I have set the environment variables as follows:

`TOKEN` ( token from BotFather )
, `PROJ` ( name of Heroku project )

AND `HEROKU` ( valueless )

After deploying,

```
2020-11-21T16:06:33.939710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-21T16:06:38.339135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2020-11-21T16:06:42.115941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-21T16:06:42.169072+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-21T16:06:41.819141+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO:aiogram:Bot: AahnikTester [@aahniks_tester_bot]
2020-11-21T16:06:41.987742+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990985+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR:asyncio:unhandled exception during asyncio.run() shutdown
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990986+00:00 app[web.1]: task: <Task finished name='Task-6' coro=<_run_app() done, defined at /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py:287> exception=TypeError('on_startup() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given')>
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990986+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990987+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 508, in run_app
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990987+00:00 app[web.1]:     loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990988+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1456, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990988+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 319, in _run_app
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990989+00:00 app[web.1]:     await runner.setup()
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990990+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 275, in setup
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990990+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._server = await self._make_server()
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990990+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 375, in _make_server
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990991+00:00 app[web.1]:     await self._app.startup()
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990991+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 416, in startup
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990992+00:00 app[web.1]:     await self.on_startup.send(self)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990992+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/signals.py", line 34, in send
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990993+00:00 app[web.1]:     await receiver(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990993+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 250, in _wrap_callback
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990993+00:00 app[web.1]:     return await cb(self.dispatcher)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.990994+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: on_startup() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
2020-11-21T16:06:41.991678+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-21T16:06:41.991741+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "bot.py", line 45, in <module>
2020-11-21T16:06:41.992057+00:00 app[web.1]:     executor.start_webhook(
2020-11-21T16:06:41.992112+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 98, in start_webhook
2020-11-21T16:06:41.992386+00:00 app[web.1]:     executor.run_app(**kwargs)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.992389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 282, in run_app
2020-11-21T16:06:41.992703+00:00 app[web.1]:     web.run_app(self._web_app, **kwargs)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.992706+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 508, in run_app
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993089+00:00 app[web.1]:     loop.run_until_complete(main_task)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993090+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "uvloop/loop.pyx", line 1456, in uvloop.loop.Loop.run_until_complete
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993309+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web.py", line 319, in _run_app
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993604+00:00 app[web.1]:     await runner.setup()
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993607+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 275, in setup
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993862+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._server = await self._make_server()
2020-11-21T16:06:41.993865+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_runner.py", line 375, in _make_server
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994180+00:00 app[web.1]:     await self._app.startup()
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994186+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/web_app.py", line 416, in startup
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994510+00:00 app[web.1]:     await self.on_startup.send(self)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994534+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/signals.py", line 34, in send
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994724+00:00 app[web.1]:     await receiver(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994724+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 250, in _wrap_callback
2020-11-21T16:06:41.994977+00:00 app[web.1]:     return await cb(self.dispatcher)
2020-11-21T16:06:41.995020+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: on_startup() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

I am looking for an example of aiogram's deployment to heroku using webhook.

#### With some tweaks to above code, this came

```
2020-11-26T09:32:27.283413+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:aiogram:Updates were skipped successfully.
2020-11-26T09:32:27.283425+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:root:Starting webhook
2020-11-26T09:32:27.455462+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING:root:Webhook set
2020-11-26T09:32:27.457534+00:00 app[web.1]: ======== Running on http://localhost:8443 ========
2020-11-26T09:32:27.457535+00:00 app[web.1]: (Press CTRL+C to quit)
2020-11-26T09:33:23.679946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

how to fix this ? ( in heroku )

#### with some other tweaks

the webhook is being set correctly because telegram is sending updates. but they are not being handled. thats why another error is coming.

```
2020-11-26T09:52:48.395734+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/webhook/secret_key..." host=radiant-caverns-48683.herokuapp.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [@evgfilim1](https://telegram.me/@evgfilim1) and [@AsyncAwait](https://telegram.me/AsyncAwait) who helped me on aiogram's [telegram group](https://telegram.me/aiogram).

Important points:

1. At async def on_startup(): and async def on_shutdown(): need dispatcher: Dispatcher

Example:

```py
from aiogram import Dispatcher

async def on_startup(dispatcher: Dispatcher) -> None:
```

2. Use `int(os.getenv("PORT"))` instead of `8443`
3. Try binding to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`

Here is a complete example for deployment of an aiogram bot that uses webhooks to fetch updates to Heroku

### https://github.com/aahnik/webhook-aiogram-heroku